ProgressBar не меняет значение, остается 100%
Работаю в Godot 4.2.2. Я делаю Тамагочи, нужны были шкалы для голода, сна и гигиены. Сделала шкалу, хотела, чтобы каждые 5 секунд значение падало на 1. Но к сожалению, у меня не получается, просто так и остается 100%. Программа не пишет ошибок.
func _ready():
await get_tree().create_timer(5.0).timeout
$Golod.value -= 1


Ваш вариант кода, создает таймер, который срабатывает один раз (SceneTreeTimer). Для того, чтобы он срабатывал множество раз, нужно использовать Timer.
Есть 2 простых способа создать таймер.

Создать объекта Timer внутри скрипта.

var counter: int = 0

func _ready() -> void:
    var timer = Timer.new()

    # Если значение равно `true` таймер автоматически запуститься, после создании сцены
    timer.autostart = true

    # Для ручного запуска таймера, используеться метод `start()`
    # timer.start()
    # И аналогично, для остановки таймера, метод `stop()`
    # timer.stop()

    # Время ожидания в секундах
    timer.wait_time = 5.0

    # Подключаем функцию, которая будет выполняться, после истечении времени таймера
    # Параметр `timeout`, это название сигнала (константная)
    timer.connect("timeout", decrease_counter)

func decrease_counter() -> void:
   counter -= 1

В данном примере, таймер уменьшает значение переменного counter на 1.

Создать объекта Timer в редакторе сцен.


Добавляем Timer в сцену и задаем параметры таймеру.



Создаем скрипт для сцены.



Подключаем сигнал timeout (сигналы находятся в окне Node) из объекта Timer к скрипту.



Пишем код, который будет выполнятся после истечении времени таймера.

func _on_timer_timeout() -> void:
    pass # Заменить на функциональный код.

